# GitLab runner doesn't load image

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

Task:
execute gradle command inside docker container during pipeline

Issue:
Solution works with default runner but not with custom.

---

Hi, I created `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
run-test:
  image: gradle:7.2.0-jdk17
  script:
    - echo "$TOOLS_DT"
    - gradle :business:test
```

When I execute this pipeline with a general gitlab runner, this runner installs image and executes `gradle` command well.

But after I registered runner on the my remote (DO) server I can't use docker images here.

Steps:

- Install docker
- Install gitlab-runner
- Register gitlab-runner with
  a) shell executor.
  b) docker executor.

Results:

- a case:

> Running with gitlab-runner 16.2.0 (782e15da)
> on first qFH8ym7TE, system ID: s_a45021325b2f
> Preparing the "shell" executor
> Preparing environment
> Getting source from Git repository
> Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
> $ echo "$TOOLS_DT"
> Byf9pMSzm1zeyGXSa232
> $ gradle :business:test
> bash: line 136: gradle: command not found

- b case:

The job can't prepare docker executor:

> Running with gitlab-runner 16.2.0 (782e15da)   on first qFH8ym7TE,
> system ID: s_a45021325b2f
> Preparing the "docker" executor 00:00
> ERROR:
> Job failed (system failure): panic: runtime error: invalid memory
> address or nil pointer dereference

So, it seems the gitlab-runner can't recognize/use docker on the my server, hovewer docker is installed:

`systemctl status docker`:

root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-fra1-01:~# systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-07-25 12:27:31 UTC; 3h 46min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Main PID: 133298 (dockerd)
Tasks: 8
Memory: 44.5M
CPU: 2.194s
CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
└─133298 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

---

How to use docker containers in gitlab ci-cd correctly?
Please help.